# Is 'git reset --soft' a no-op command?

Tags: git, git-reset

The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-reset) states that leveraging the `--soft` option *"...Does not touch the index file nor the working tree at all, but requires them to be in a good order. This leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put it"*.

It also explains that the target `<commit>` defaults to HEAD, when not given.

Considering these, does the following command modify anything at all?

`$ git reset --soft`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Considering these, does the following command modify anything at all?

No, it is a no-op.

After thinking about this for a bit: technically it will complain if you are in the middle of a merge with unresolved conflicts however all that this means is that instead of doing nothing, it complains and does nothing.