# git fetch && git reset --soft not updating commits

Tags: git, redmine

So I want a very simple git script to update my repository on github via cron every 10 minutes, so that my bug tracking system can pick up those changes.

Before creating said script I did a bare clone because this really isn't a workspace, its just for our issue tracking system (Redmine). The bare clone works just fine, and when we go into the issue tracker we can easily see all the commits.

```
git clone --bare git@github.com:yoyodyne/coolproject.git coolproject.git
```

An I am expecting to update this repo via cron like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT=/opt/bitnami/git/bin/git
cd /var/redmine/git_repositories/coolproject.git && $GIT fetch 
  && $GIT reset --soft
```

But when the cron runs it *does not* update new commits and returns the following message:

```
From github.com:yoyodyne/coolproject
* branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

I have used this approach before on other projects and it works completely, in fact I used this approach as a template from a previous project. The links below have been read pretty much front to back and I am still shooting blanks.

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRepositories

http://gitref.org/remotes/

Comment: You shouldn't need reset, because there is no worktree nor index associated with a bare repository

Comment: Why do the Redmine docs tell me to do this? That's a copy paste. Bad docs? Looking into your suggestions, will report results.

Comment: well I get an error when I try to git checkout master (that's what I am thinking you mean by "ref")

>fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

Comment: git pull is not allowed on a bare clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did a ton of searching and I found this an obscure posting about refs not working.

https://github.com/koppen/redmine_github_hook/issues/10

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT=/opt/bitnami/git/bin/git
cd /var/redmine/git_repositories/welocally-places.git && 
  $GIT fetch origin '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*' && $GIT reset --soft
```

I changed my script and it worked, the only sad thing is that I feel like a monkey who imitates the strange hairless apes.

Comment: You can (and should) ditch the `reset --soft`. It doesn't do anything. Also you can adjust the config of your repository to use that refspec by default when using a parameterless fetch.

Answer (score 3):

I've no idea why the documentation recommends doing a `git reset` in a bare clone, `git reset` isn't valid in a bare repository (even though `--soft` doesn't actually change the index or working tree) and if it did work it would be a [no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712555/is-git-reset-soft-a-no-op-command).

The simplest thing to do would be to set up a fetch rule that mirrors all the branches and tags:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Then a simple `git fetch` will update all the branches and tags of this clone from the remote repository in a similar way to how it would if it had been set up with `git clone --bare --mirror`.

Comment: Effing leeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeegend. Exactly what I needed, this makes for a neat crontab line without my current one (which for some reason has sets of &&'s...). 1UP

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with a bare repository. Don't use reset. Git checkout ref -- . would be better. That or git archive.

You could use reset if you specify the work tree and the git repo. That's an alternative to setting the environment variables. These options are available on the git command itself.

Comment: well I get an error when I try to git checkout master (that's what I am thinking you mean by "ref")

>fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree

Comment: `checkout` is just as invalid for a bare repository as `reset` is. You have to use `git symbolic-ref HEAD` to change the `HEAD` in a bare repository but this isn't really solving the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use

```
git clone --mirror
```

instead of  --bare repo for git -fetch to work as you want it